# Asp.net mvc authorize attribute integrated with a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use an `[Authorize()]` attribute in the following way on an action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator" or UserId == id)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id){ }
```

Right now I'm using logics like this:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator") || User.Identity.Name.Equals(id))
        { }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you an access everything piece of functionality the controller has inside the Attribute:

See:

[How to pass parameters to a custom ActionFilter in ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348071/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-custom-actionfilter-in-asp-net-mvc-2/4348206#4348206)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. In .NET attributes can use only constant values. On the other hand you could write a custom authorize attribute deriving from the standard one and in the [AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore.aspx) method implement this logic.