# Creating custom ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an ActionFilterAttribute called LayoutAttribute and added it to the ActionResult:

Controller:

```
    [Layout(PageType.Department,"dnr")]
    public ActionResult Kd(string mainBody, int dnr)
    {
```

LayoutAttribute:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Komplett.Infrastructure.NInject;
using Ninject;


namespace Minion.Services.PageState
{
  public class LayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    private readonly PageType _pageType;
    private readonly string _pageIdName;

    public LayoutAttribute(PageType PageType,string PageIdName = "")
    {
        _pageType = PageType;
        _pageIdName = PageIdName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var pageStateModel = KernelContainer.Kernel.Get<PageStateModel>();
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(_pageIdName ?? ""))
        {
            pageStateModel.PageId = (string)filterContext.ActionParameters[_pageIdName];
        }
        pageStateModel.PageType = _pageType;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that OnActionExecuting is never called.
I also tried to register the attribute in global.asax.cs, but then I needed a parameterless constructor. I created this and added it to global.asax.cs like this:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LayoutAttribute());
```

This, without any luck.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make MVC call OnActionExecuting?

Comment: You should not need to register it in the Global Filters. Are you sure there are not any other filters intervening before yours and redirecting the page?

Comment: Use properties, like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348071/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-custom-actionfilter-in-asp-net-mvc-2. Most likely a non-default constructor is not supported.

Comment: What happens if you put it on controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're implementing

```
System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
```

and not

```
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
```

They both have OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted Methods, so it can be a little deceiving