# How to pass parameters to actionfilter in different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I have checked the answers in here.
[How to pass parameters to a custom ActionFilter in ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348071/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-custom-actionfilter-in-asp-net-mvc-2)
I want to check a condition in several controllers, based on a unique id that is passing into the controller.

here is the code for actionfilter.

```
public class AnswerCompletedAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public string p { get; set; }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(p))
        {
            var id = filterContext.ActionParameters[p] as Guid?;
            if (Db.IsRespondentAnswerCompleted(id))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                    { "controller", "Error" },
                    { "action", "NotFound" }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my code in the controller,

```
[AnswerCompleted(p = "uniqueId")]
    public ActionResult Index(Guid? uniqueId)
    {

        //do something
        return View();
    }
```

How should I change it to make it work?

Comment: Please explain the error you are getting?

Comment: @ Arathy T N There is no error, the filter doesn't work. It won't stop the action loading.

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is inherited from the wrong class,
it should be `system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute` instead of `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`